# How do I catch an exception when my .NET Framework Web API loads?

Tags: c#, exception, asp.net-web-api, milestone

I'm having an issue where I need to catch a FileNotFoundException when my application starts. For further context, this is a Web API that is also using the Milestone SDK. In their (Milestone SDK) developer forums, I found someone else who was having a similar issue and attempted the same things I have. The post provided some guidance, but the solution isn't exactly clear.

For reference: [Milestone SDK Developer forum question](https://developer.milestonesys.com/s/question/0D50O00005UKrvP/combine-camerastreamresolution-with-aspnet)

One of the Milestone reps answered the question like this:

> Bo Andersen (Milestone Systems A/S)
>
> We are speculating that you need these files in the current folder when you
>   execute your service, we have seen issues where the current folder is
>   no longer the expected folder, ***we suggest that you catch the
>   exception, and when the exception is caught you get the current folder
>   and logs it.***

The problem I'm having is that I have yet to find a way to catch the exception given the exception happens as soon as I start to debug the application.

**EDIT**

Adding some code samples per request:

```
//Bookmarks.cs in my models
    public Bookmarks(DateTime timeBegin, FQID fqid, string header, string description)
            {
                TimeBegin = timeBegin;
                Fqid = fqid;
                Header = header;
                Description = description;

                BmReference = BookmarkService.Instance.BookmarkGetNewReference(Fqid, true);

                TimeBegin.AddMinutes(-1);
                TimeEnd = TimeBegin.AddMinutes(1);
                TimeTrigged = TimeBegin.AddSeconds(30);
            }


//Global.asax.cs
     public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
        {
            protected void Application_Start()
            {
                    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
                    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
                    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
                    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

                    VideoOS.Platform.SDK.Environment.Initialize();          // General initialize.  Always required
                    VideoOS.Platform.SDK.UI.Environment.Initialize();
                    VideoOS.Platform.SDK.Export.Environment.Initialize();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you please share the code where you have first called/used Milestone SDK APIs?

Comment: @MKR It's kind of spread out - some in my models and initialize in the application_start() in Global.asax.cs - none of the code is being called on which is why I didn't include it in the original question but if you think it'll help diagnose the issue I can add it.

Comment: You can try wrapping all codes of `Application_Start` in `try/catch` and see if it catches exception.

Comment: @MKR I tried that - I set a break point there as well and that's when I get the warning "The Breakpoint will not be hit. No symbols loaded..."

Comment: Though its not allowing you to `debug` but you can still check if it was able to catch exception by setting some variable from `catch` block.

Comment: @MKR - As I said before, I tried catching an exception there to no avail.